Prevent auto-maximizing windows on Kubuntu 24.04 KDE Plasma?
I'm using Kubuntu 24.04 with KDE Plasma 5.27.11, and I have two screens with different orientations – one horizontal and one vertical.
When I move a maximized window from one screen to another, it automatically snaps and maximizes according to the other screen's orientation.
I want to prevent this behavior, so the window size and position stay the same when moving between screens. Here's some additional information about my system:
Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Graphics Platform: X11
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

I've already tried changing the "Window Placement Strategy" to "Under Mouse Cursor"
However, this didn't solve the issue.
Is there any other configuration or workaround to stop windows from automatically maximizing/snapping when moving them between screens with different orientations?
Thank you in advance for your help!
